# jquery mobile and bootstrap in phonegap build

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am building an app in phonegap build using jQuery mobile. I am using jquery mobile cause it gives more native app look. But bootstrap is the best for responsive images. When I tried to add both jQuery mobile and bootstrap it did not work out very well. I did not see any jQuery framework. So is there a way to use both jQuery and bootstrap. Or is there a way to add responsive images in jQuery mobile.

Comment: How can you use your keyboard for programming, if the shift is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use jqm and its nice because it's simple but it really isn't suitable for a lot of things imho.

I can't solve your problem but I can suggest this - switch to Ionic now and you'll have native looking apps that are more responsive using the same technology you already know.